# Set height for android switch widget

Tags: android, switch-statement

I'm running 4.0 and greater and embedding an android "Switch" in my xml layout. I'd like to control the size of this widget. Setting layout height did nothing... Any ideas?

```
        <Switch
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:switchPadding="10dp"
    android:textOff="Slide to Unlock"
    android:switchTextAppearance="@style/test1"
    android:thumb="@drawable/unlock_selector"
    android:track="@drawable/unlock_background_selector" />
```

Comment: I didn't have any luck with the "switch" widget, but the actual problem I was trying to solve was to create a "lock screen" swipe to answer call view. After much searching I found the native android private implementation made to work with a sample project: https://github.com/nadavfima/GlowPadView  

Hope it helps someone